# Need help to make site with webView with external link handling like "magnet"

Tags: android, url, android-intent, android-webview, magnet-uri

I have made a simple app from website with webView. It's a torrent site. I post magnet link in the site. What I want is when I click on only magnet link all torrent app like bit-torrent will catch the address automatically. Plus all other external site link will open in external browser like Chrome.

I have followed some online tutorial even from here (stackoverflow) but they are old and used `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but Google says that this method was deprecated in API level 24.

Here https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
I have followed google to use this code.(modified to match with my site) but its not working. please someone help me with this.

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
```

This my java main activity code now.now every link in the site open in webview but I don't want that and for magnet link it shows like this snapshot.

[image: error]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    // Configure related browser settings
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    // Configure the client to use when opening URLs
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    // Load the initial URL
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    try {
        activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                packageName, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex1) {
        return false;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex2) {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException ex3) {
        return false;
    } catch (Exception ex4) {
        return false;
    }

}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

   if (url.startsWith.("magnet")) {

    if(isAppInstalled('com.bittorrent.client')){

 PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
 Intent appStartIntent = 
  pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage('com.bittorrent.client');
   getApplicationContext().startActivity(appStartIntent);

   }else{

   // No matching app found, toast it.
     }
}
     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: hlw thanks for the code appreciated but i m having some problem with the code.sorry to say that im very new in this. 

    `public boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    try {
        activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                packageName, 0);`

here activity is showing "cannot resolve symbol activity" in red

Comment: and here ' if (url.startsWith. ("magnet"))'

here startsWith is showing "cannot resolve symbol startsWith" in red.

Comment: activity is the instance of your current activity, you can also use getPackageManager() directly in the Activity code.Just clean the code as the second commented issue is quite weird & unexpected.

Comment: Also please use latest version of  shouldOverrideUrlLoading method if you are targetting Nougat (API level 24) & above.

Answer (score 0):

use this:  updated with Nougut support. Remember to upgrade your sdk api level to 25 in Android studio. otherwise you could get error.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

@Override

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("magnet")) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            try {
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Team localpeers:  No bittorent client installed in system.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String url=request.getUrl().toString();
        if (url.startsWith("magnet")) { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            try {
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Team localpeers:  No bittorent client installed in Android.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the magnet links, I remembered a while ago I manage to link the magnet link simply by loading the url from the webview, unfortunately this solution didn't worked on my phone (One Plus 5 running on Oreo).

My solution to this issue:

1. You need to scrape the url or urls you want to show to the user. In my case I have a recycle view where the user can chose one item (movie) which he can download. In order to scrape the data I used those libraries:

   implementation "pl.droidsonroids:jspoon:1.3.0"
   implementation "pl.droidsonroids.retrofit2:converter-jspoon:1.3.0"

You can check here on how actually you need to use those libraries from here [link](https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/jspoon).
After you scrape your data you need to show to the user a list (in my case) of the items that the user can download, when the user click on one of the items you basically use the
magnet url that you scraped before and apply simply this code:

```
String url = "your magent url";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

No need to use any webviews or custom WebViewClients.

**A small note** (I checked if the user have a torrent application before he could manage to download any torrents you simply use the packagemanager and check if any of his applications contains torrent).

I only checked this solution on my phone

Comment: FYI the verb is __scrape__, past tense __scraped__, also __scraper__, __scraping__. To scrap means to throw away like rubbish or to fight.